# Are "due to" and "because of" equal?

Tags: phrase-usage

Are "due to" and "because of" equal - i.e. due to something and because of something?

Can I use it with context of *reason*?

Answer (score 8):

There are still a few pedants pontificating over correct usage of [**Owing to** vs **Due to**](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/owing-to-vs-due-to/), but I'm not aware anyone has ever objected to replacing either with **because of**.

So, yes - you can use **because of** or **due to** to link a cause to an effect (i.e. - to specify a **reason**)...

> 1: OP asked this question because of his uncertainty
>    2: OP asked this question owing to his uncertainty
>   3: ?OP asked this question due to his uncertainty

I've never had a problem with #3, but as that link says, some people object to it on the grounds that *due to* is "adjectival", and should thus reference a *noun* (not a *statement*, such as *"OP asked this question"*).