# "Because of" and "Due to" after adjective

Tags: word-usage

I am aware that this is an old question, been discussed

- [Are "due to" and "because of" equal?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5984/are-due-to-and-because-of-equal)
- [Usage of "due to" and "because" - are they interchangeble?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7288/usage-of-due-to-and-because-are-they-interchangeble)

Having "due to" is more adjectival, although I am not that particular, but what if the word in front is adjective?

e.g.

- Climbing that mountain is difficult due to its height, or
- Climbing that mountain is difficult because of its height.

Comment: They are [different](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/because.html). The reason they are not interchangeable is that they “grew up” differently in the language.

Comment: So which one of the two sentences I provide is correct?

Comment: You may use the second variant: 'Climbing that mountain is difficult because of its height'.

Comment: Any particular reason the first one is invalid?

Comment: Didn't you follow the link I provided?

Comment: Sorry my computer brightness was bit low that time. So can I say that in this case, "because of" is adverbial so it modifies the adjective "difficult"?

Comment: The verb 'is difficult' is explained by the adverbial prepositional phrase: 'because of'

Answer (score 1):

Most of grammar books describe that *due to* acts more adjectival. We all know but this question (+1, of course) forces me to dig in deeper. And, I found something useful...

> In the book *Woe Is I The Grammarphobe’s Guide to Better English in Plain English*, the author proposes to substitute **"due to"** for *“caused by”* or *“resulting from.”* She explains that if a sentence begins with “due to,” as in “Due to inclement weather, school was canceled,” the sentence is “probably wrong.” - *Grammar Girl*

While keeping general rules aside for a special case like this (adjective ahead), I think following this rule does not harm the structure.

Having said that,

> Climbing that mountain is difficult **because of** its height -sounds preferable to me.

**Note** - COCAE shows results of both the usages (*...difficult because of...* and *...difficult due to ...)* but then the former returns with over hundred results, the latter sticks around a couple of dozens.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "Due to" can, in a very specific context, refer to the holder of a debt. Consider the following example:

```
"The money due to the bank had not been paid."
```

It is not at all uncommon, however, to see the phrase "Due to" used in a "*because*" context, such as the following:

```
"Due to circumstances beyond our control, today's meeting has been cancelled."
```

Answer (score -1):

both usage is right in your sentences.

to elaborate the difference, the usage of "due to" is found in more formal / legal situations.

e.g. 
1) I got delayed because of traffic (not due to)
2) The cash payable due to him broke me.
3) I like ice cream because of its chillness.
4) His emotions were twisted due to Shakespearean plays.